# XSLT - Select node from templates based on map

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This is a sample xml content I've written for explain purpose,

```
<doc>
    <array>
        <?Table_type Small?>
        <table>
            <data>text</data>
        </table>
    </array>

    <array>
        <?Table_type Medium?>
        <table>
            <data>text</data>
        </table>
    </array>

    <array>
        <?Table_type Large?>
        <table>
            <data>text</data>
        </table>
    </array>
</doc>
```

Here you can identify 3 types of tables, table containing processing instruction value Small, Medium and Large. (in actual document there are more tables types are there)

what I want to do is, by checking table type (identify using processing instruction) add `size` attribute to `<data>` nodes.

since there are large number of table types existing in original document I uses following XSL method to do this task,

```
<xsl:variable name="table.type.mapping">
        <map parent='Small' mapto='10'/>
        <map parent='Medium' mapto='20'/>
        <map parent='Large' mapto='30'/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="data[ancestor::array/processing-instruction('Table_type')=$table.type.mapping/map[@parent=ancestor::array/processing-instruction('Table_type')]/@parent]">
        <data size="{$table.type.mapping/map[@parent=ancestor::array/processing-instruction('Table_type')]/@mapto}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

But it's does not read corresponding attribute value from the map and placed in corresponding `<data>` node.

My expected output is,

```
<doc>
    <array>
        <?Table_type Small?>
        <table>
            <data size="10">text</data>
        </table>
    </array>

    <array>
        <?Table_type Medium?>
        <table>
            <data size="20">text</data>
        </table>
    </array>

    <array>
        <?Table_type Large?>
        <table>
            <data size="30">text</data>
        </table>
    </array>
</doc>
```

Any suggestion how I change my template for read correct value from the map and add correct attribute to the `<data>` node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done very conveniently (and efficiently) by using a **key** to do the lookup:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="table.type.mapping">
    <map parent='Small' mapto='10'/>
    <map parent='Medium' mapto='20'/>
    <map parent='Large' mapto='30'/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="size" match="map" use="@parent" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data">
    <data size="{key('size', ancestor::array/processing-instruction('Table_type'), $table.type.mapping)/@mapto}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need the complicated xpath expression in the match itself, especially if all `data` elements have a valid processing instruction before them.

The main problem is with the AVT for calculating the `size` attribute. It is looking for an ancestor of the `map` element, not the current `data` element. It should be this...

```
<data size="{$table.type.mapping/map[@parent=current()/ancestor::array/processing-instruction('Table_type')]/@mapto}">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:variable name="table.type.mapping">
        <map parent='Small' mapto='10'/>
        <map parent='Medium' mapto='20'/>
        <map parent='Large' mapto='30'/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <data size="{$table.type.mapping/map[@parent=current()/ancestor::array/processing-instruction('Table_type')]/@mapto}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If some `data` elements don't have corresponding processing instructions, try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:variable name="table.type.mapping">
        <map parent='Small' mapto='10'/>
        <map parent='Medium' mapto='20'/>
        <map parent='Large' mapto='30'/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <data>
            <xsl:variable name="size" select="$table.type.mapping/map[@parent=current()/ancestor::array/processing-instruction('Table_type')]/@mapto" />
            <xsl:if test="$size">
                <xsl:attribute name="size" select="$size" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have been falling into the trap of the [Resulting tree fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37417752/1305969) which is a serious problem of XSLT-1.0.

One way to avoid that is transforming your `<xsl:variable>` into a data island in your XSLT file. This data island needs an own namespace I called `var` which has to be excluded explicitly from the result by using the `exclude-result-prefixes` directive.

Furthermore, I did use two variables to avoid namespace clashes between the XML and the XSLT namespace.

FYI: `document('')/xsl:stylesheet` does refer to the XML root node of the current XSLT document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:var="some.var" exclude-result-prefixes="var">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <var:tabletypemapping>
        <map parent='Small' mapto='10'/>
        <map parent='Medium' mapto='20'/>
        <map parent='Large' mapto='30'/>
  </var:tabletypemapping>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:variable name="procIns" select="ancestor::array/processing-instruction('Table_type')" />
    <xsl:variable name="mapIns"  select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/var:tabletypemapping/map[@parent = $procIns]/@mapto" />
    <data size="{$mapIns}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity template left untouched -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <array>
        <?Table_type Small?>
        <table>
            <data size="10">text</data>
        </table>
    </array>

    <array>
        <?Table_type Medium?>
        <table>
            <data size="20">text</data>
        </table>
    </array>

    <array>
        <?Table_type Large?>
        <table>
            <data size="30">text</data>
        </table>
    </array>
</doc>
```

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Of course your right. I just recognized that after posting my answer.